# How to mark folders with color in Pycharm

Tags: ide, pycharm

I want to mark specific folders with color. For example folder which is finished should be marked with green color, not finished red and etc. I want them to work same as "mark directory as"  but instead only changing color. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What does `finished` mean in your scenario?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke there are no # TODO s in that specific folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found plugin for PyCharm called [ProjectTree Color Highlighter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13951-projecttree-color-highlighter), does exactly what I need:

[image]

Comment: this also works for Goland - Thanks for the Hint

Answer (score 0):

In principle no. File and folder colours in PyCharm are dependent on the [file status in the version control system](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html) and on the [content root category](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html).

However, you could use [scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#associate-file-color-with-a-scope) to [associate a color with a set of files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#associate-file-color-with-a-scope).

If you're looking to filter `#TODO` items, PyCharm has a built in TODO tool window under `View | Tool Windows | TODO`.
This will show you all folders with `#TODO` items, or show folders in a certain scope with `#TODO` items.
Additionally you can [add your own custom filters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-todo.html#add_pattern_filter_todo) to find specific `#TODO` comments.

Comment: can i manually assign specific scope to folders?

Comment: Did you read the links I posted?

Comment: yes and I came to conclusion that it assigns color scopes automatically which wont really help me. am i wrong?

Comment: Nothing happens automatically, it's all based on how *you* define your scopes. You can also define scope colors, but I don't have PyCharm at hand to test if this only works for files or also for folders.
However, as your actual problem revolves around finding TODO items I think the second part of my answer applies.

Comment: it partially helps me yes, but I want to have multiple types of filters like, finished, unfinished, partially finished and etc.

Comment: Can you please, pretty please, read my answer. I'll retype the relevant part here: Additionally you can [add your own custom filters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-todo.html#add_pattern_filter_todo) to find specific #TODO comments.
There I think you can add filters to find `#TODO finished` or `#TODO unfinished`. If not, please rewrite your question to show what you've tried and what the erroneous result is.